# Angular project creation failed because of deprecated circular-json

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, npm

I used following command to create new angular project

```
ng new hello-world
```

It failed showing

```
npm WARN deprecated circular-json@0.5.9: CircularJSON is in maintenance only, flatted is its successor.
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...rocess":"~0.7.0"},"_h'
```

Then I installed flatted using...

```
npm i flatted
```

But the error still occurs. 
How to use flatted instead of deprecated library circular-json?

Comment: Is it "failed"? Or was there simply a "WARN" message displayed by `npm` during initialization. If you have some reason to believe the initialization "failed" then please be specific about what is not working for you. But this appears to be just another deprecation warning. Real world projects have deprecated dependencies all of the time.

Comment: You got 2 logs, a warning and an error. 1st one can be safely ignored, the error needs to be addressed. Seems like your package.json got corrupted at some step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run following commands that will clean NPM cache

> npm cache clean --force

after this run following command

> npm install -g @angular/cli@latest

then you can create angular project.

Comment: clean npm cache and install angular

Comment: worked for me! but need to open the terminal as an administrator. Some warnings did occur though.

Answer (score 1):

If it doesn't work, even after clearing the cache, which happened in my case:

Make sure you try the `ng new create-app` command using Powershell in **administrator** mode.

This worked for me.

Comment: sudo ng new my-app ..  FTW! :-D Then all the 'deprecated' warnings disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. None of the above mentioned answers worked for me.

So I **removed** the content of `.npmrc`, ran the generate command and it worked.

After that, you can restore the content of your `.npmrc` if needed.